# Bukkit Coding - Config.yml How do I allow players to have {target} and {sender} in there and it shows up as the sender name and target name in game

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

How do I allow players to have {target} and {sender} in there and it shows up as the sender name and target name in game?

Heres my code:

```
package proewarns.me;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import proewarns.me.SettingsManager;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    SettingsManager settings = SettingsManager.getInstance();

    public void onEnable() {
            settings.setup(this);
            getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveConfig();
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("warn")) {
            if (!sender.hasPermission("proewarn.warn")) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are not permitted to do this!");
                    return true;
            }
            if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;

            }



        final Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Could not find player!");
            return true;
        }


        Object level = settings.getData().get(target.getName());


        if (level == null) {
            settings.getData().set("" + target.getName() + "", 1);
            settings.saveData();
            target.sendMessage(this.getConfig().getString("PlayerMessage") + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "(1/3)");
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(this.getConfig().getString("WarnMessage") + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "(1/3)");
            return true;

        }

        int l = Integer.parseInt(level.toString());

        if (l == 1) {
            settings.getData().set("" + target.getName() + "", 2);
            settings.saveData();
            target.sendMessage(this.getConfig().getString("PlayerMessage") + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "(2/3)");
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(this.getConfig().getString("WarnMessage") + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "(2/3)");
            return true;
        }
        if (l == 2) {
            settings.getData().set("" + target.getName() + "", null);
            settings.saveData();
            target.kickPlayer(this.getConfig().getString("BanMessage"));
            target.setBanned(true);
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(this.getConfig().getString("Tempbanbroadcast") + ChatColor.DARK_RED + "(3/3)");           
            Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            target.setBanned(false);
                    }
            }, 1500 * 20);
            return true;


        }
            return true;


    }
        return true;



    }
}
```

Heres my config.yml:

```
BanMessage: You have been temp banned for 25 Minutes

WarnMessage: {target} Has been warned by {sender}

PlayerMessage: You have been warned by {sender}

TempbanBroadcast: {target} has been temp banned by {sender}
```

How would I make it so {target} would show up as the player getting warned and {sender} would show up as the sender?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to use the `.replace()` or `.replaceAll()` methods

Quick example

```
player.sendMessage(getConfig().getString("hello").replaceAll("{name}", player.getName());
```

Config:

```
hello: 'Welcome {name}'
```

This will send the following message to the player if his username is Notch:

```
Welcome Notch
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.replace()` methods:

```
public String fixString(String original, String target, String sender){
  return original.replace("{target}", target).replace("{sender}", sender);
}
```

You could then use this in your `onCommand` method, or wherever you would like to use it:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
  if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test") && args.length == 1){
    String original = "{target} Has been warned by {sender}";
    String new = fixString(original, args[0], sender.getName());
    Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(new);
  }
}
```